Rotating the keyboard from landscape to portrait with keyboard open leaves a white area
I'm developing a web app with Flutter (version 3.27.0 but had same issue with 3.24).
I deployed the app on a web server with flutter build web --release.
Using the web app on a Android (Samsung) device on multiple browsers (Chrome, Firefox and the default Samsung one) I noticed that whenever I rotate the screen from landscape to portrait with the keyboard open I get that the screen space previously used by the keyboard inset turns white and becomes unavailable for the app in a similar way to resizing the screen. Then, the app runs as expected in the remaining part of the screen. When I rotate the screen again, the full screen is used again by the web app.
The same issue happens whenever LastPass is automatically opened while writing the username or password (in this case even in portrait).
On iOS the issue IS NOT present, probably due to the different rendering engine.
This problem happens on any screen which allows to open up the virtual keyboard.
To verify that the issue is not code-related I implemented the following basic screen with only a Scaffold and a TextFormField, which also presents the aforementioned problem:
class TestScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const TestScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<TestScreen> createState() => _TestScreenState();
}

class _TestScreenState extends State<TestScreen> {
  final TextEditingController _controller = TextEditingController();

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Center(
            child: Container(
      margin: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16, vertical: 4),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.white, borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16)),
      child: TextFormField(
        controller: _controller,
        autocorrect: false,
        enableSuggestions: true,
        keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
        maxLines: 8,
        onSaved: (value) {},
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          hintText: "Add text here",
          hintStyle: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyMedium,
          alignLabelWithHint: true,
          border: InputBorder.none,
        ),
        style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyMedium,
        autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction,
        validator: (value) {
          if (value!.isEmpty || value.length < 16) {
            return "Input is too short".hardcoded;
          }
          return null;
        },
      ),
    )));
  }
}


I attach in the following some images of the observed behaviour.
base screen on portrait
I go landscape and open the keyboard
Going back to portrait with keyboard open creates this white area
Has anyone ever found something similar? It seems like the Scaffold is not properly resized on some occasions. At the time of writing I unfortunately cannot test this behaviour on native Android/iOS without an extensive rewrite of code.
I tried to build the web app with web-renderer html, however it did not solve the problem. I tried to compile the web app with wasm, however I couldn't manage to configure the web server in a way that makes it be actually used by browsers.
I tried to set resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false on the scaffold. It seems to fix the issue on Firefox but no on Chrome.
flutter doctor -v does not report any issue.
Thank you!
